# how to use fold and reduce in grouping in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I know how to use `reduce and fold` operations but, I'm not getting how to use it with map.

```
 val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
 println(numbers.groupingBy { it.first() }.eachCount())      // Output:- {o=1, t=2, f=2}
```

grouping returns Map. So, i need to figure out how to use fold and reduce with kotlin Map.

Any example is ok. I just need to use reduce and fold with grouping in kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously never used this in my project. You can understand the code below.

`it % 5` gives various remainder values `0,1,2,3,4`
i.e `5%5 = 0 ; 5%6 = 1; 5%7= 2; 5%8 = 3; 5%9 = 4; 5%5 = 0`

```
val numb = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
    val nmap = numb.groupingBy { it % 5 }
    println(nmap.eachCount())
    println("map =  ${nmap.reduce { key, accumulator, element ->
        println("$key ($accumulator,$element)")
        accumulator + element
    }}")
```

Output

```
{1=4, 2=4, 3=4, 4=4, 0=4}
1 (1,6)
2 (2,7)
3 (3,8)
4 (4,9)
0 (5,10)  ---> 5 +
1 (7,11)
2 (9,12)
3 (11,13)
4 (13,14)
0 (15,15)  ----> 5 + 15 +
1 (18,16)
2 (21,17)
3 (24,18)
4 (27,19)
0 (30,20) -----> 5 + 15 + 30

map =  {1=34, 2=38, 3=42, 4=46, 0=50}
```